# Prove $p:E\to B$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $p:E\to B$ be a covering projection.

$E$ is path connected, $B$ is simply connected.

Prove $p:E\to B$ is a homeomorphism (bijective surjective, continuous and open).

---

I don't understand something basic...

It seems to me as if it's always true regardless of whether $B$ is simply connected.

Observe the preimage $V=p^{-1}(B)\subseteq E$.

*from the definition of $p$ follows:* $B$ is open hence $V$ is open and is the union of disjoint open sets $V=\cup V_\alpha$.

Now $p^{-1}(B)=\{e\in E | p(e)\in B\}=E$, hence $V=E$.

But $E$ is path connected hence connected, so it cannot be the union of disjoint open sets, so there must be a single set in the union $\{V_\alpha\}_\alpha=\{V\}$. and $p|_{V_\alpha}=p|_V = p|_E = p:E\to B$ is homeomorphism.

Where did I go wrong?
Does the definition of $p$ holds only for proper subsets of B?
If you can, please put me in the right direction :)

Comment: it's not true if $B$ is not simply connected. Think of $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$, $p(t)=e^{i2\pi t}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $p: E \to B$ being a covering map:

> Each point $x \in E$ has an open neighborhood $V$ whose preimage is a disjoint union of open sets $W_\alpha$ such that each $p: W _\alpha \to V$ is a homeomorphism.

You seem to have chosen $V = B$. You then show this implies $W_\alpha=E$ and so $p$ is a homeomorphism.

But according to the definition you do not get to choose what $W_\alpha$ looks like. You only know it exists. That's the problem.

Comment: Ashamed of myself :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proof you gave is wrong as Daron showed.

But theorem 54.4 in Munkres (2nd edition) says :

> let $p:E \to B$ be a covering map. Let $p(e_0) = b_0$. If $E$ is path connected, then the lifting correspondence (defined the paragraph above this theorem )
>   $$\pi_1(B, b_0) \to p^{-1}[\{b_0\}]$$ is a surjection.

Now, $B$ is simply connected so for any $b_0 \in B$, $|\pi_1(B, b_0)|  =1$, and this theorem implies then that all $p^{-1}[\{b_0\}]$ are singletons too.

So $p$ is 1-1 and all covering maps are surjective, open (even local homeomorphisms) and continuous. So $p$ is a homeomorphism.